# How to use pg:psql in heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to detect my db at heroku terminal like this:

```
myapp@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/myapp$ heroku pg:info
The plugin heroku-sql-console has been deprecated. Would you like to remove it? (y/N) n
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.1.6
Created:     2012-10-10 19:59 UTC
Data Size:   9.1 MB
Tables:      32
Rows:        2802/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
```

So, I tried:

```
myapp@ubuntu:~/RubymineProjects/myapp$ heroku pg:psql
The plugin heroku-sql-console has been deprecated. Would you like to remove it? (y/N) n
psql (9.1.7, server 9.1.6)
SSL connection (cipher: **-**-****-**, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.
```

I need to list all users records:

```
dbfjinfaes61gb=> select * from users
dbfjinfaes61gb->
```

But above, nothing happened, what I am missing here?

Comment: SQL requires the `;` at the end of the query

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need a semicolon at the end of the query:

```
select * from users;
```

Comment: Thanks! yes its the semicolon was missing .. now I can see the result and 'END' at the end of it, how can I proceed to enter the next command?

Answer (score 13):

Run this

```
heroku pg:psql -c "command" --app "name-app"
```

sample

```
heroku pg:psql -c "\?" --app app-sample
```